# Estimating a truncated or partial distribution curve

Tags: r, scipy, statistics, curve-fitting, distribution

I have a sample of only 142 numbers from a distribution of 3852 numbers ranging from 0 to 53, but it is truncated below 35, so I have all the values in the right tail from 35 to 53. Is it possible to estimate what kind of distribution this is, with just these 142 numbers? And also calculate the mean, standard deviation (or other parameters) of this curve?  Using Scipy, R, Matlab, or any method?

```
sample= [53,53,51,49,49,49,48,48,48,47,47,47,47,47,47,46,46,46,46,46,45,44,44,44,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35]
```

Comment: This might be better to post in Stack Exchange. Once you know what method you can use, post here to find out how to apply it with R

Comment: [This Stack Exchange answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229624/fitting-truncated-distributions-using-fitdistrplus-with-a-lower-bound-of-zero) might help.